# How to calculate weighted average of a categorical variable in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, stata, numpy-ndarray, statsmodels

I am trying to calculate stunting in children aged 0-5 years old in India. I have loaded the datasets from the DHS websites for children. I have my Y variable columns as:
a> hw70 (with 0= not stunted and 1= stunted)

Attributes columns:

- a> sex_children(male= 1, female= 0)
- b> weight columns(wt= v005/1000000) for the sample (.26 mn household) given by DHS themselves.

In stata it was easier to tabulate the hw70 and sex_children(iweight= wt) which removes any kind of weight bias present in the result.

In python I am using cross tabs to find the output. But how to apply given sample weights for the sample data set for a categorical columns like sex_children?

In stata:

```
tab hw70 sex_children[iweight=wt], row

nt_ch_stun |     sex_children
      hw70 |      male     female |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
         0 | 66,638.05  63,547.39 | 130,185.4 
           |     51.19      48.81 |    100.00 
-----------+----------------------+----------
         1 | 37,892.08  33,674.05 | 71,566.13 
           |     52.95      47.05 |    100.00 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total | 104,530.1  97,221.45 | 201,751.6 
           |     51.81      48.19 |    100.00
```

How to do the same in Python especially the iweight part? I am using cross tabs but getting very limited information with weight bias. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: There's [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), which can do a cross tabulation. I am not sure I understand what applying the sample weights means.

Comment: Yes, I am using pd. crosstab() to do a cross-tabulation. The female individual sample weight (v005) is provided as a column in the dataset. In Stata, applying this weight to the sex_children column was easier which represented the exact percentage of males and females present in the sample. But how do I tabulate  sex_children[iweight=wt] with the Y-label as I did in Stata, in Python?

Comment: Is the idea to filter for rows where the iweight column is equal to some value?

Comment: No Nick. The idea of weight is a bit complex. Sampling weights in a stratified sample are adjustment factors applied to each female in tabulations to adjust for differences in the probability of selection of females compared to males. Hence, weights are applied to produce the proper representation of females in the sample. The individual weight for women (v005) is the household weight (Given at the Household level) multiplied by the inverse of the individual response rate for women in the stratum. Unable to understand how to treat a categorical variable sex_children with individual weights.

Comment: maybe the `aggfunc` keyword in `crosstab` can be used to request a weighted mean or sum. (Not that I ever used it)

Answer (score 1):

Not having a sample of the data makes it unsure but here is how to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

# load sample dataset into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sex': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    'age': [3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3],
    'height': [80, 70, 85, 65, 90, 80, 70, 95, 75, 85],
    'weight': [10, 8, 12, 7, 14, 10, 8, 16, 9, 12],
    'stunting': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
})

print(df)

wts = df['weight'] / 1000000

xtab = pd.crosstab(df['stunting'], df['sex'], values=wts, aggfunc=sum, normalize='index')

xtab = xtab.applymap(lambda x: '{:,.2f}'.format(x))
xtab.columns.name = 'sex'
xtab.index.name = 'stunting'
xtab.loc['Total'] = xtab.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
xtab = xtab.append(xtab.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1).rename('Total'))
xtab.iloc[:,[1,0,2]]
```

which will return somthing like this

```
             1     0  Total
stunting                   
0         0.00  1.00    NaN
1         1.00  0.00    NaN
Total      NaN   NaN    NaN
Total      0.0   0.0    0.0
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Will let you know whether it worked or not. Thanks.